# XNA / Monogame Texture2D to to string

Tags: c#, xml, xna, monogame, texture2d

I want to store a small png image in a XML file and Load it back to Texture2D.

This is what I'm doing

Code for saving

I'm writing the data of the Texture2D with the BinaryWriter to a MemoryStream,

then converting the MemoryStream to an Array. I have to Convert the array to a Base64String because you can't save all characters

in a XML file.

The string is saved in my XML file.

```
    public static string SaveTextureData(this Texture2D texture)
    {
        int width = texture.Width;
        int height = texture.Height;
        Color[] data = new Color[width * height];
        texture.GetData<Color>(data, 0, data.Length);

        MemoryStream streamOut = new MemoryStream();

        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(streamOut);

           writer.Write(width);
            writer.Write(height);
            writer.Write(data.Length);

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                writer.Write(data[i].R);
                writer.Write(data[i].G);
                writer.Write(data[i].B);
                writer.Write(data[i].A);
            } 

        return Convert.ToBase64String(streamOut.ToArray());
    }
```

Code for Loading

Same here.. I'm converting the Base64Str to an array and trying to read it.

But I cant read it back.

```
    public static Texture2D LoadTextureData(this string gfxdata, GraphicsDevice gfxdev)
    {
        byte[] arr = Convert.FromBase64String(gfxdata);

        MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream();

        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(input);
        bw.Write(arr);

        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(input))
        {
            var width = reader.ReadInt32();
            var height = reader.ReadInt32();
            var length = reader.ReadInt32();
            var data = new Color[length];

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                var r = reader.ReadByte();
                var g = reader.ReadByte();
                var b = reader.ReadByte();
                var a = reader.ReadByte();
                data[i] = new Color(r, g, b, a);
            }

            var texture = new Texture2D(gfxdev, width, height);
            texture.SetData<Color>(data, 0, data.Length);
            return texture;
        }
    }
```

Could need some help here.

Getting an exception in the reading method that the value couldnt read.
in line

`var width = reader.ReadInt32();`

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what problem you are having? "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.

Comment: Getting an exception in the reading method that the value couldnt read.
in line                 var width = reader.ReadInt32();

Comment: Did you try debugging anything? See what reader looked like? its going to be next to impossible to debug this for you.

Comment: In the future, when asking for help with an exception on StackOverflow, please be sure to include the full `ToString()` output of the exception, including the exception type and traceback.  In this case you are receiving an exception of type `System.IO.EndOfStreamException` which is a big hint as to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [create a `MemoryStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) directly from your byte array, no need to fill it with a writer:

```
        byte[] arr = Convert.FromBase64String(gfxdata);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(arr))
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(ms))
        {
            var width = reader.ReadInt32();
            var height = reader.ReadInt32();
            var length = reader.ReadInt32();
            var data = new Color[length];

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                var r = reader.ReadByte();
                var g = reader.ReadByte();
                var b = reader.ReadByte();
                var a = reader.ReadByte();
                data[i] = new Color(r, g, b, a);
            }

            // Allocate the Texture2D as before.
        }
```

(The specific problem with your code is that you did not rewind your `input` stream after writing to it.)

Comment: Creating a MemoryStream directly from the array solved the problem :) Thank you very much.